# Magento 2 - losing the theme after module:enable

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

So in Magento 2, I seem to lose all of the static assets after I install a module. This is what happens:

```
bin/magento module:enable [module name or --all]
```

Which of course tells me:

> To make sure that the enabled modules are properly registered, run
>   'setup:upgrade'.

Now the issue is when I run:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

All of the pregenerated static files are gone. The whole admin and store frontend breaks.

Then I have to run a bunch of commands to process and re-generate all of the required files. Now, please tell me I am making a noob mistake here. I might be on the wrong mode etc.

How do you guys handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can run the setup upgrade command and keep the static content:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

One more thing, if we want the static content to re-generate on fly automatically and create the symlink, we need to delete static folders(`_requirejs`, `adminhtml`, `frontend`), DON'T delete `.htacess`. Make sure our application mode is developer or default. Refresh the page, it takes time to re-generate the static content on fly. And then, we don't need to run the static command every time.

Comment: Great stuff. `.htaccess` obviously doesn't work for Nginx - is there something I need to do for Nginx for the rewrites to work properly?

Comment: I assume the `.htaccess` file contains mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Sorry, I do not try with Nginx. We should try with `nginx.conf.sample` of default Magento.